# Avoiding Fibonacci-like sequences

Tags: integer-sequences

Suppose we are trying to avoid 3-term arithmetic progressions. There are two relevant sequences in the OEIS pertaining to this:

[A003278](http://oeis.org/A003278): The sequence whose $n^{\text{th}}$ term is the smallest number $k$ for which a sequence of length $k$ avoiding any 3-term AP exists.

[A065825](https://oeis.org/A065825): The sequence whose $n^{\text{th}}$ term is the smallest number $k$ for which the range $1\ldots k$ contains some sequence of $n$ numbers that avoids a 3-term AP.

A three-term AP is of course a set of numbers $a, b, c$ such that 
$$ a + c = 2b$$

My question is this:

> Are there known sequences/results in either of the above formulations
>   for a different "fibonacci-like" obstacle: namely, a 3-term sequence
>   $a, b, c$ such that
>
> $$a + b = c$$

Comment: I think if you search for "sum-free sets" you'll find a lot of work on these. Alternatively, figure out the first few terms, and look it up in the OEIS.

Comment: I would suggest this question would be more interesting if you sought a sequence that is Fibonacci free, alongwith being 3-AP free simultaneously. Also, to avoid trivial all-even or all-odd solutions, I'd enforce both the following variants of Fibonacci freeness: $f(a)+ f(b) \neq f(c)$ and $f(a) + f(b) \neq f(c) + 1$.

Comment: @user17348 that's a good point, and is actually what I was really looking for. I thought I'd ask about this as an intermediate case.